# iOS paint optimization

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontext

Hi I am currently working on an app that contains taking notes by drawing. I followed ray wenderlich tutorials and as far I've got, I ended up with this code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
} 

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGFloat red,green,blue,alpha;

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];



    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),[self getBlendMode]);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x , lastPoint.y  );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x , currentPoint.y  );
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [self getBrushSize] );

    [[self getPaintColor] getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),[self getBlendMode]);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:[self getPaintAlpha]];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGFloat red,green,blue;

    if(!mouseSwiped) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [self getBrushSize]);

        [[self getPaintColor] getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:nil];
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, [self getPaintAlpha]);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y - self.mainImage.frame.origin.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y - self.mainImage.frame.origin.y );
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);

    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:[self getBlendMode] alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:[self getBlendMode] alpha:[self getPaintAlpha]];
    if(self.drawMode != DrawEraser)
    {
        self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    mouseSwiped = NO;
}
```

This code was working just fine with a small frame but when I increased the frame as 2 times bigger than before, unfortunately performance is not so good. So I was thinking about optimizing the code. I especially focused on touchesMoved method. As far as I understand, it draws the whole image on the context and changes it some and assigns the context to image. Drawing whole image seemed to be overload. So I was wondering, if I can draw some parts of the image to the context and do some changes and then draw this part of the context to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right - redrawing the whole image every time in touchesMoved is a bad idea. I think you should create and keep a reference to the context at the beginning. In touches moved, you should draw on to that and create an image from the context. You can use `CGBitmapContextCreate()` to create the context instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` and  `CGBitmapContextCreateImage()` to create an image from the context instead of `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`. Here is the documentation on how to use those (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html).